# How to debug the php syntax error when it is in a html file?

Tags: php, vim, sublimetext3

```
<?php
        if($val['shift_z']==1){
          $arr=$val['shift_zone'];
          if(count($arr)>=1&&is_array($arr)){
?> 
//html code
//html code
//html code
//html code
//html code
<?php
          }
        }
?>
```

like the above code,if I miss the  `<?php }} ?>` ,it tells me: the last line unparse $.I don't know the "lacking }" line number.
I installed sublimeLinter but I am not sure how to configure it to show this error, in vim,I also use the `syntastic` plugin which not display any errors.
I also use zendstudio to open this file it still can't tell me which line the error is.
In the end, I have to check every {} to debug the error,but this is too slow.

Comment: please paste the error message

Comment: If you miss `<?php }} ?>` the interpreter will stumble upon the end of the file... knowing that we're in a block and still looking to meet the block ending. There isn't block ending. What exactly line number do you wish to see in the error message? The error happens at the very end of the file.

Comment: You just dont make sense.  Which what? Which line? Last one!

Comment: yes,the error message just show the last line number,I want to know where the } should be added.

Comment: At the very end of the file, d'oh!

Comment: From what I can tell, you're opening a bracket and there's no statement after... that could be your problem

Comment: If you are using an editor with brackets highlighting, you can put a closing bracket at the very end of the file and then look up the highlighted bracket above it

Answer (score 1):

To show all php errors and notice alerts on the screen put the following lines in the top of your PHP file:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with php's error reporting is that it skips lines between 
`?> and <?` - it counts only the lines of actual php code.

Try this:

http://www.piliapp.com/php-syntax-check/

It even marks the line after the missing bracket.